# Deleting duplicate values in std map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have a

```
map<char,my_class*> mymap;
```

the contents of which are as below.

```
mymap[0]=('a', 0x1);
mymap[1]=('b',0x2);
mymap[3]=('c',0x3);
mymap[4]=('d',0x1);
```

As you see we have same value for keys 'a' and 'd'. i have a for loop to delete the pointers in the map.

```
for ( it=mymap.begin() ; it != mymap.end(); it++ ){
  delete it->second;
}
```

It crashes because it is trying to delete 0x1 twice. 
I tried doing this

```
for ( it=mymap.begin() ; it != mymap.end(); it++ ){
  if(!it->second){
      delete it->second;
      it->second = NULL;
  }
}
```

Even this tries to set a pointer to NULL twice which result sin an exception. 
What is the best way to delete duplicate values as above in a map?

Comment: Setting a pointer to NULL twice does **not** result in an exception. Deleting the same pointer twice might do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NPE's answer involving `shared_ptr` is good. But if you're forced to use real pointers, I'd probably do it like this:

```
set<my_class*> values;
for (it=mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++)
{
  // insert.second will be false if the value is already in the set
  if (values.insert(it->second).second)
    delete it->second;
}

// Make sure you do something with mymap to ensure you don't double-delete later!
```

Comment: To avoid double-delete later just do `it->second = 0;`

Comment: Note that formally, this solution has undefined behavior, since once you've deleted an object, you're not allowed to access pointers to it.  (In practice, I cannot imagine it causing any problems, at least on a modern general purpose machine.)

Comment: @JonathanWakely And how does that help?  Setting one pointer to null won't change the value of any other pointers in the container.

Comment: @JamesKanze I wasn't saying it solves the OP's problem, I suggested it as a solution for the comment _Make sure you do something with mymap to ensure you don't double-delete later!_ If you leave dangling pointers in the map and someone  later does `for(auto i : mymap) delete i.second;` it will be safe if the pointers are null, not otherwise. Another option would be `mymap.clear()` but maybe the keys are still wanted.

Comment: To solve the UB problem you could insert every `it->second` into the set then in a second loop got through the set and `delete` everything in it

Comment: @JamesKanze - really? After I've deleted an object I can't even _refer_ to its memory address? How weird. Is it possible to make this "clean" - say, by making the set hold `void*`, and using `reinterpret_cast` on insert?

Comment: You can't in C++11, but it's implementation-defined in the latest draft, see [DR 1438](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1438)

Comment: @Chowlett According to the language standard (both C and C++), once you delete an object, any pointers into that object become invalid.  The same state as an uninitialized object.  And invalid pointers can contain trapping values, such that just reading the pointer (lvalue to rvalue conversion) can cause the program to crash.  I've actually used systems where this was the case (but before C++ even existed).

Comment: @JonathanWakely Setting `it->second = NULL` doesn't do anything to prevent a double delete.  The OP's original problem is that he has several different pointers to the same object.  Setting one of them to null won't affect the others (and he only processes each pointer once).

Comment: @JonathanWakely Interesting.  Why they decided to change from "undefined" to "implementation defined by might crash", I don't know; the final effect is almost the same.  (But there is a precedent.  The C standard specifies converting to a signed numeric type where the value doesn't fit in a similar way.  I think that that case, however, is historically conditioned: C90 says that it has an implementation defined result, and the change was to make it clear that that result could be a signal.)

Comment: it means most implementations (where a pointer to deleted memory is just a number) can say it works, but weird ones that trap on accessing the pointer value aren't obliged to support it. I don't remember any more of the discussion though, sorry

Answer (score 4):

My advice would be to keep [`shared_ptr<my_class>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in your map, and sidestep the problem altogether.

If you can't do that, you'll need to keep an auxiliary container (e.g. a `set`) of pointers that you've already deallocated. You'll then consult and update that container as you're iterating over the map.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want duplicate second entries, then perhaps the
best solution would be to not insert them to begin with.  The
cleanest solution I can think of to do this would be to use
Boost bimap.  I rather think this behavior would surprise the
user who inserted the second entry, however.

Alternatively (supposing you can't use `shared_ptr`), the
simplest solution when deconstructing the map would be to create
a temporary `std::set<MyClass*>` with all of the elements, and
then delete from that.  (`std::set` ensures no duplicates).

And while I'm at it: the reason your second solution fails isn't
because you are setting a pointer to null twice; there's nothing
wrong with that.  It is because you have two distinct pointers
to the same object; setting the first to null doesn't modify the
second, so you still end up trying to delete the same object
twice.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler if you stored the instances or used a smartpointer. Std::Map has its own internal pointers to your object, and you can save headache by relying on someone elses handle to your object. The `Boost` library contains several smartpointers. If you use an intrusive reference counting smartpointer, then your object can be automatically destroyed when it is removed from the map.

You will then be able to use the erase function to remove the value from the map, which will then delete your object (if it is the last reference) after calling the destructor chain.